# Unable to create Tomcat configuration file with `files` tag in .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm learning how to use ebextensions to customize files on the EC2 instances created by Elastic Beanstalk.

So I downloaded the Tomcat [java-tomcat-v3.zip sample application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/samples/java-tomcat-v3.zip) at this [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/RelatedResources.html) and modified its `.ebextensions/logging.config` file.

Below is my `logging.config`:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/bundlelogs.d/01-sample-app.conf":
    content: |
      /tmp/sample-app*

  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/taillogs.d/01-sample-app.conf":
    content: |
      /tmp/sample-app.log

  "/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: tomcat
    content: |
      RewriteRule ^/API(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [NC,L]

  "/tmp/test.txt":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: tomcat
    content: |
      hello there
```

The file `/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config` is not created after I deploy the zip file to my Elastic Beanstalk environment.

All the other 3 files are correctly created.

What's wrong with my configuration?

There are some messages about `rewrite.config` file in `/var/log/eb-activit.log`:

```
[2019-01-04T03:26:32.983Z] INFO  [6912]  - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-9@13/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/02clean.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k tomcat_version
  + TOMCAT_VERSION=8.5
  + '[' 8.5 == 8.5 ']'
  + TOMCAT_VERSION=8
  + TOMCAT_NAME=tomcat8
  + mkdir -p /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
  ++ readlink -f /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/..
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_BASE_DIR=/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps
  + rm -rf /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
  + rm -rf /usr/share/tomcat8/conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config
  + rm -rf /usr/share/tomcat8/work/Catalina/localhost
  + mkdir -p /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
[2019-01-04T03:26:32.983Z] INFO  [6912]  - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-9@13/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/02start_xray.sh] : Starting activity...
```

I don't understand why elastic beanstalk executed `rm -rf /usr/share/tomcat8/conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config` command during deployment.

Is there any command that deletes `/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config` after the file is created?

The following is the full content of `/var/log/eb-activity.log`:

```
[2019-01-04T05:20:41.410Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:41.411Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:41.411Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AddonsBefore/ConfigCWLAgent] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:41.411Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AddonsBefore/ConfigCWLAgent/10-config.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:41.533Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AddonsBefore/ConfigCWLAgent/10-config.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Log streaming option setting is not specified, ignore cloudwatch logs setup.

  Disabled log streaming.
[2019-01-04T05:20:41.533Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AddonsBefore/ConfigCWLAgent] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/logstreaming/hooks/config.
[2019-01-04T05:20:41.533Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2019-01-04T05:20:41.921Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:41.921Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/DownloadSourceBundle] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:42.440Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/DownloadSourceBundle] : Completed activity. Result:
  [2019-01-04T05:20:42.024Z] INFO  [12019] : Application version will be saved to /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource.
  [2019-01-04T05:20:42.024Z] INFO  [12019] : Using manifest cache with deployment ID 15 and serial 15.
  [2019-01-04T05:20:42.024Z] INFO  [12019] : Attempting to download application source bundle to: '/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle'.
  [2019-01-04T05:20:42.024Z] INFO  [12019] : Using computed s3 key.
  [2019-01-04T05:20:42.142Z] INFO  [12019] : Downloading from bucket 'elasticbeanstalk-region-n-xxxxxxxxx' with key 'resources/environments/e-ipdsfn2umb/_runtime/_versions/BrianTest/java-tomcat-v3-11' and version '' to '/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle'.
  [2019-01-04T05:20:42.226Z] INFO  [12019] : Size: 6511344, ETag: "025d9af7b40ad70f45caed145adfce0f", Metadata: {"environmentid"=>"e-ipdsfn2umb", "requestid"=>"5d54090a-0fe0-11e9-9bda-6373967d51b5"}.
  [2019-01-04T05:20:42.431Z] INFO  [12019] : Downloaded size: 6511344.
  [2019-01-04T05:20:42.431Z] INFO  [12019] : Successfully downloaded to '/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle'.
[2019-01-04T05:20:42.441Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:42.836Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:42.840Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_0_BrianTest] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:42.840Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_0_BrianTest] : Completed activity.
[2019-01-04T05:20:42.845Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_1_BrianTest] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:42.845Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_1_BrianTest] : Completed activity.
[2019-01-04T05:20:42.845Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild] : Completed activity.
[2019-01-04T05:20:42.863Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild] : Completed activity.
[2019-01-04T05:20:42.863Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:42.864Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01_configure_xray.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:43.030Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01_configure_xray.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  D, [2019-01-04T05:20:42.968092 #12033] DEBUG -- : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
  D, [2019-01-04T05:20:42.968243 #12033] DEBUG -- : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::CloudFormation::Init||Infra-WriteApplication2||files..
  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/log-conf -n awsxray -l'/var/log/xray/xray.log' -t publishlogs

[2019-01-04T05:20:43.030Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01clean.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:43.127Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01clean.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/tmp/deployment/application/ROOT
  + rm -rf /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT
  + mkdir -p /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT
[2019-01-04T05:20:43.128Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/02unzip.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:43.384Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/02unzip.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/tmp/deployment/application/ROOT
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k source_bundle
  + EB_SOURCE_BUNDLE=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
  + /usr/bin/unzip -o -d /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
  Archive:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
     creating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/META-INF/
   extracting: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  
     creating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/
     creating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/
     creating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/org/
     creating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/org/example/
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/org/example/AWSXRayServletContext.class  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/org/example/AWSXRayServlet.class  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/org/example/ConditionalAWSXRayServletFilter.class  
     creating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/
   extracting: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/NOTICE.txt  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/LICENSE.txt  
     creating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ion-java-1.0.1.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.6.6.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/httpclient-4.5.2.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.67.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/commons-validator-1.5.1.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jmespath-java-1.0.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.6.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.8.1.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/httpcore-4.4.4.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-1.0.5-beta.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.67.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core-1.0.5-beta.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.67.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/cron.yaml  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/index.jsp  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/scheduled.jsp  
     creating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/src/
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/src/AWSXRayServlet.java  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/src/ConditionalAWSXRayServletFilter.java  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/src/AWSXRayServletContext.java  
     creating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/.ebextensions/
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/.ebextensions/xray.config  
    inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/.ebextensions/logging.config  
  ++ wc -l
  ++ find /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT -maxdepth 1 -type f
  + FILE_COUNT=3
  ++ wc -l
  ++ ls /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT --almost-all
  + ITEM_COUNT=7
  + [[ 3 == 0 ]]
[2019-01-04T05:20:43.384Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03_configure_proxy.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.069Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03_configure_proxy.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Executing: /bin/chown root:apache /var/run/httpd

  Executing: /bin/chmod 755 /var/run/httpd

  Executing: /bin/chown apache:apache /var/log/httpd

  Executing: /bin/chmod 755 /var/log/httpd

  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/log-conf -n httpd -l'/var/log/httpd/*'

  Executing: /usr/sbin/apachectl -t -f /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
  Syntax OK
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.069Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03config_clean.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.168Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03config_clean.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k config_staging_dir
  + EB_CONFIG_STAGING_DIR=/tmp/deployment/config
  + rm -rf /tmp/deployment/config
  + mkdir -p /tmp/deployment/config
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.168Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/04config_generate.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.483Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/04config_generate.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/generate_config
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.483Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre.
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.483Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.880Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.880Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Completed activity.
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.895Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Completed activity.
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.895Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/InfraCleanEbextension] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.896Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0/InfraCleanEbextension] : Completed activity. Result:
  Cleaned ebextensions subdirectories from /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT.
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.896Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage0] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy stage 0 completed
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.897Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.897Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:44.897Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01stop.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:46.432Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01stop.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k tomcat_version
  + TOMCAT_VERSION=8.5
  + '[' 8.5 == 8.5 ']'
  + TOMCAT_VERSION=8
  + TOMCAT_NAME=tomcat8
  + /etc/init.d/tomcat8 status
  tomcat8 (pid 8226) is running...[  OK  ]
+ /usr/bin/monit unmonitor tomcat
  + /etc/init.d/tomcat8 stop
  Stopping tomcat8: [  OK  ]
[2019-01-04T05:20:46.432Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01stop_xray.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:48.548Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01stop_xray.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Executing: if ( initctl status xray | grep start ); then initctl stop xray; fi
  xray start/running, process 8071
  xray stop/waiting
[2019-01-04T05:20:48.549Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/02clean.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:48.742Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/02clean.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k tomcat_version
  + TOMCAT_VERSION=8.5
  + '[' 8.5 == 8.5 ']'
  + TOMCAT_VERSION=8
  + TOMCAT_NAME=tomcat8
  + mkdir -p /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
  ++ readlink -f /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/..
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_BASE_DIR=/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps
  + rm -rf /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
  + rm -rf /usr/share/tomcat8/conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config
  + rm -rf /usr/share/tomcat8/work/Catalina/localhost
  + mkdir -p /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
[2019-01-04T05:20:48.742Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/02start_xray.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:48.855Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/02start_xray.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Executing: initctl start xray
  xray start/running, process 12243
[2019-01-04T05:20:48.855Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/03_stop_proxy.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:49.447Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/03_stop_proxy.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Executing: service nginx stop

  Executing: service httpd stop
  Stopping httpd: [  OK  ]
[2019-01-04T05:20:49.447Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/03deploy.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:49.644Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/03deploy.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/tmp/deployment/application/ROOT
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
  ++ wc -l
  ++ find /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -path '*/\.*'
  + FILE_COUNT=3
  ++ grep -Pi '\.war$'
  ++ find /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT -maxdepth 1 -type f
  ++ echo ''
  + WAR_FILES=
  + WAR_FILE_COUNT=0
  + [[ 0 > 0 ]]
  ++ readlink -f /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/../
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps
  + rm -rf /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
  + [[ 3 == 0 ]]
  + cp -R /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
  + chown -R tomcat:tomcat /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps
[2019-01-04T05:20:49.644Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/04config_deploy.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:49.921Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/04config_deploy.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k config_staging_dir
  + EB_CONFIG_STAGING_DIR=/tmp/deployment/config
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k config_deploy_dir
  + EB_CONFIG_DEPLOY_DIR=/etc/sysconfig
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k config_filename
  + EB_CONFIG_FILENAME=tomcat8
  + cp /tmp/deployment/config/tomcat8 /etc/sysconfig/tomcat8
[2019-01-04T05:20:49.922Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/05start.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:50.082Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/05start.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k tomcat_version
  + TOMCAT_VERSION=8.5
  + '[' 8.5 == 8.5 ']'
  + TOMCAT_VERSION=8
  + TOMCAT_NAME=tomcat8
  + /etc/init.d/tomcat8 status
  tomcat8 is stopped
  [  OK  ]
+ /etc/init.d/tomcat8 start
  Starting tomcat8: [  OK  ]
+ /usr/bin/monit monitor tomcat
[2019-01-04T05:20:50.082Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/09_start_proxy.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:53.246Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/09_start_proxy.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Executing: service httpd stop
  Stopping httpd: [FAILED]
  Executing: service httpd start
  Starting httpd: [  OK  ]
  Executing: /bin/chmod 755 /var/run/httpd

  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --proxy httpd

  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-configure --appstat-log-path /var/log/httpd/healthd/application.log --appstat-unit usec --appstat-timestamp-on 'arrival'

  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-restart

[2019-01-04T05:20:53.246Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact.
[2019-01-04T05:20:53.246Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:53.246Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/03monitor_pids.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:53.929Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/03monitor_pids.sh] : Completed activity.
[2019-01-04T05:20:53.930Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post.
[2019-01-04T05:20:53.930Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AppDeployStage1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application version switch - Command CMD-AppDeploy stage 1 completed
[2019-01-04T05:20:53.930Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:53.930Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:53.930Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-04T05:20:54.287Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Disabled forced hourly log rotation.
[2019-01-04T05:20:54.287Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/logpublish/hooks/config.
[2019-01-04T05:20:54.287Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2019-01-04T05:20:54.287Z] INFO  [11976] - [Application update java-tomcat-v3-11@15] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy succeeded
```

I've found that there's a command `rm -rf /usr/share/$TOMCAT_NAME/conf/Catalina/localhost/*` sitting inside `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/02clean.sh`.

Probably this is the reason that I can't create a file under `/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/Catalina/localhost/`.

My ultimate goal is to use [Tomcat rewrite valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html). I think I have to look for another solution.

Comment: is this the complete log that you have posted ?

Comment: No, it's not. It's part of the log.

Comment: can you post the full log may be we are missing something

Comment: You can try removing `rewrite.config` from your logging.config file and see if EB Cli still running `rm -rf` command or not.

Comment: `rm -rf` command disappears after I remove the `rewrite.config` file.

Comment: @varnit. I'll post the full log after I remove sensitive information in the log.

Comment: Have you tried with `group: root` ?

Comment: @Ahmadreza, setting `group: root` doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 0):

I created the `/tmp/rewrite.config` file with `files`.

Then, using `postdeploy` hook I created a script to copy it to the `/etc/tomcat/Catalina/localhost/` folder

This is the path to the hook `/src/main/platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_add_rewrite_config.sh`